# Compensation of forward voltage drop of a diode - software

Tags: microcontroller, adc, compensation

In my case I would like to compensate with software a voltage drop over the diode.
I have diode RS2J which supplies DC/DC (50mA - 200 mA) converter at this point with resistor divider I would like to measure the voltage with ADC calculate the input voltage before the diode.
Out of my calculations the compensation with single value  (ex. 800mV) is out of tolerance because it depends from  temperature and input current.

Do you know any kind of software method which could help to reach higher accuracy.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3xzus.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Some simplified schematic.

Comment: A schematic would be very helpful and would allow us to help you better.

Comment: You don't want to do what you think you want to do.
Sample the actual input voltage, bypassing the diode. Use a simple inexpensive FET to disconnect the voltage divider from the ADC when you are not using it. If you don't get what I am saying, let me know and I will draw a schematic for you.

Comment: Why is the diode there? Input polarity protection or something else?

Comment: Put the voltage divider before the diode.

Comment: The diode is due to  revers polarity. I simplified a bit the circuit diagram , after the diode I have PMOS which switch of power supply in case in not needed and reduce the leakage current  ( battery supply device ).

Comment: What is the maximum input Voltage you would like to design for? Is it really 26V? If it is 8V, there is a simple way to provide reverse polarity protection with a "backwards" PMOS. You connect the gate to GND, connect the drain to the battery Voltage, and connect the source to the system voltage. Under positive polarity, the FET will turn on. Under reverse polarity, it will turn off, and the body diode will be reverse biased. But this circuit will become problematic if you try to make it work at 26V, because there aren't many transistors that can take 26V Vgs.

Comment: I know that . In my opinion the Vgs is not a problem . You can always protect it with Zenner diode .

Answer (score 3):

Well, no.  In this case, trying to compensate for diode drop with software and trying to achieve high accuracy doesn't sound like the best idea.  You would need to know the current and temperature of the diode to be able to calculate the voltage drop.

Connecting the voltage divider to the voltage that you actually want to measure would be a better idea.